# Select a table where columns get values from cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:
feedproducts
[image]
and proDataSpecification:

[image]

I am trying to create a table from both, so it should get the "keyName" from "proDataSpecification" and then loop in the columns of table "feedproducts" and get the values of thus columns. In the end the result should be:

[image]

My code:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @proName nvarchar(50)
declare @CursorVar cursor
set @CursorVar= cursor scroll dynamic
for
select column_name
from [test].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='feedproducts'
open @CursorVar
fetch next from @CursorVar into @proname
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin 
if
   @proName !='' and @proName is not null
   set @sql=
           'select
                 ltrim(rtrim('+@proName+')) as val, 
                 abs(checksum(newid()))%1000 
                 as valId, [test].[dbo].[proDataSpecification].KeyId

          from [test].[dbo].[feedproducts]

          inner join [test].[dbo].[proDataSpecification] on 
         '+@proname+'=proDataSpecification.KeyName

         group by '+@proName+', KeyId';

exec sp_sqlexec @sql
fetch next from @CursorVar into @proName
end;
close @CursorVar;
deallocate @CursorVar;
```

So: 
val column gets values from rows of feedproducts, valId column is just random number, keyId column takes values proDataSpecification[keyId].

I run the upper code but I have two problem:

- I got this error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'id' to data type int.".
- It cost a lot of time to finish.

could you please help me to correct it and make it fast. 
I don't have that experience with sql server 2008, so please don't just add min and go, add explanation instead of it. thanks.

Comment: you don't need a cursor, and a cursor is what is taking so long. It's unclear what the resulting columns come from and how. ACTUAL sample data and EXPECTED results would help out a lot here.

Comment: hi scsimon, thanks for replying. In the table result : val column gets values from rows of  feedproducts, valId column is just random number, keyId column takes value proDataSpecification[keyId].

Comment: So can you post sample data and expected results, preferably with a DDL and DML?

Comment: Yes I can do that but feedproducts table is too big and for each column I have to execute like this code:

 select distinct ltrim(rtrim(title)) as val, abs(checksum(newid()))%1000 as valId, [test].[dbo].[proDataSpecification].KeyId
from  [test].[dbo].[feedproducts]
inner join [test].[dbo].[proDataSpecification] on 'title'=proDataSpecification.KeyName
group by title,KeyId

Comment: Hi  scsimon, Could you please again check for me the the code in the comment and give some advise How can I get the same result but without cursor. If you see the code in the comment, this piece of code I have to repeat it about 70 times to git the same result as cursor.